translation module not installed in Delphi Community Edition V12
I have installed the new Delphi Community Edition V12 and the translation module doesn't appear, even though it was installed in version V11.
I tried re-installing version V12 after uninstalling version V11, but it didn't change anything

Should probably ask this question on a Delphi support forum. Not here.
